# Laravel sum order price relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Guys i need to sum total price for current order. Order can have many products with diferent qty and prices. I need to call relation and summ all for for current order. I try with hasMany and belongTo but not work. Can someone see what i do wrong. Here is my database structure and code.

**NOTE**: *I not provide full database colums and full code becouse code is big and here not be clear. I get just part what is need to understand.*

**Order table**

```
id    |   order_number   |  customer_id  |  status_id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    OR00123       |    1          |     1
```

**OrderProducts table**

```
  id    |   order_id   |  product_id    |  qty      |    
------------------------------------------------------
   1    |    1         |  5             |  1        |

   2    |    1         |  2             |  2        |

   3    |    1         |  6             |  3        |
```

**Product table**

```
  id    |   name            |  price  
----------------------------------------
   5    |    iphone         |  1231            

   2    |    samsung        |  2322             

   6    |    someproduct    |  432
```

**Models**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "orders";


    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'subjekat_id');
    }

    public function Product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(OrderProduct::class);
    }

    public function Products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class);
    }
}

// Product
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "products";

    public function Category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}

// Customer

class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "customer";


    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'poste_id');
    }
}

// Order products

class OrderProducts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "order_products";

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'proizvod_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMan(Product::class);
    }

}
```

**What i do**

```
$orders = Order::get();

  @if($orders)
        @foreach($orders as $order)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->customer->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->customer->address->street }}</td>
            
           <!-- HERE I NEED TO SUM ALL ORDER PRODUCTS-->
           <td>{{ $order->products->sum('price')}} </td>       
        </tr>
    
  @endforeach
 @else
```

When i call sum i get

```
Call to a member function sum() on null
```

Comment: what `dd(Order::get());` outputs? i guess u want to retrieve them all? `Order::all()`

Comment: also, try to follow conventions, `public function Product()` should be `public function product()` (camelCase), etc

Comment: i come from C# there we all time white UpperCase and bad practice stay!!!

Comment: each language has their conventions, just dont mix them

Comment: Okay here convetions is not problem.

Comment: so u tried what i said u in the 1st message or what?

Comment: @Techno there is an `Order` model in the question

Comment: Yes i have order model.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad :)

Comment: For this i think need to go $order->orderProducts->product->price. i think i need deeper relations

Comment: @Ivan Over which orders are you looping and do all orders have products?

Comment: I think you should use withSum()

Comment: Yes sistem is not new this is refactoring just. There is about 3400 orders and all have products.

Comment: I have Order model where i define relation to table OrderProducts and in OrderProducts model i have relation to access in Product where i have product name and product price. So when i try from Order Model to access to products i get that table but when i try to go deeper from OrderProducts to Product i get Property [product] does not exist on this collection instance.  Example: $order->orderProducts->product->price

Comment: Is this a typo or something else? `$this->hasMan(Product::class);` *'hasMan' instead of 'hasMany'*

Comment: In addition, in the blade template, you tend to use `{{ $order->products->sum('price')}}` with lowercase *'products'* yet your relationship is uppercase *'Products()'*